# How do I attach a click event to all div's assigned to a certain class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know anything about jquery so  yeah. I just want so that when you click the "image-url" divs they set the "src: component to the img tag and have the image appear upon clicking. Really appreciate the help.

the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>CIS 230 Fall 2012</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="midterm.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="labs/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.image-url').click(function() {
        $("#image").attr("src", $(this).attr("val"));
        $("#image").attr("hidden", "false");
    });
})();

function imageload(ls) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "../images/" + ls;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><div style="float:left; width:40%;"></div><div style="float:right;"></div><h1 class="title">CIS 230</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="links">
    <div id="link-holder">
        <h3>Labs:</h3>
        <a href="labs/xhtml1.html"><div class="url">xhtml 1</div></a>
        <a href="labs/csslab1.html"><div class="url" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="leave(this)">css lab 1</div></a>
        <a href="labs/csslab2.html"><div class="url" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="leave(this)">css lab 2</div></a>
        <a href="labs/csslab3.html"><div class="url">css lab 3</div></a>
        <a href="labs/csslab4.html"><div class="url">css lab 4</div></a>
        <a href="author.html"><div class="url">author page</div></a>
        <a href="labs/dogfish.html"><div class="url">dog fish</div></a>
        <a href="labs/corners.html"><div class="url">rounded corners</div></a>
        <a href="labs/columns.html"><div class="url">div columns</div></a>
        <h3>Images:</h3>
        <div id="image-link-holder">
            <div class="image-url" val="me.jpg">Beautiful Me</div> //so they click this
            <div class="image-url" val="monster.jpg">Godzilla</div>
            <div class="image-url" val="bandw.jpg">Black and White</div>
            <div class="image-url" val="duocolor.jpg">DuoColor</div>
            <div class="image-url" val="washed.jpg">"Washed" Look</div>
            <div class="image-url" val="fade.jpg">Faded</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="image-holder" style="min-width:400px; background-color:#000000;" hidden="true">
        <img id="image" src="" alt="No Image Specified" /> //and my mug shot will appear hopefully
    </div>
    <div id="links-spacer1" style="min-width:400px; min-height:300px"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    <h1>Web Design and Development:</h1>
    <h2>We cover a lot of things:</h2>
    <p>We first review basic HTML and cover CSS styles</p>
    <p>Labs made:
    <ul>
        <li>css lab 1</li>
        <li>css lab 2</li>
        <li>css lab 3</li>
        <li>css lab 4</li>
    </ul>
    </p>
    <p>Once we have the basics down we can cover some more advanced styling. Especially using the &amp<div></div>&amp; tags
    </p>
    <p>Labs made:
    <ul>
        <li>sunny.html</li>
        <li>dogfish</li>
        <li>columns</li>
    </ul>
    </p>
    <p>Then We move onto the graphical component of web design, where we mess around with photoshop</p>
    <p>Labs made:
    <ul>
        <li>monster.jpg</li>
        <li>duocolor.jpg</li>
        <li>other stuff...</li>
    </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<p id="disclaimer">This webpage is the work of a student. It is not associated with the <a href="www.sunyocc.edu">SUNY Onondaga Community College.</a> The author of this web page is Jason Dancks, and generated with Dreamweaver. If you think this asshole might have stolen your intellectual property, <a href="mailto:jddancks@yahoo.com">email him</a> or contact his <a href="mailto:stedmant@sunyocc.edu">professor</a> or call him at: (315) 498- 2326</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I don't know anything about jquery so yeah." Well considering this is a lab for a 200 level CIS course maybe it's time you learned?

Comment: "If you think this asshole might have stolen your intellectual property" lol

Comment: why use hidden? it doesn't work for the most popular browser

Comment: First time I'm hearing this. So what should I do? use $(this).hide or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take the value of attribute "val" for the image you click, and replace the 'src' attribute of the img tag with class "image" with the value: here's how you do that.

```
$('.image-url').on('click', function(){
   var img_url = $(this).attr('val');
   $('#image').attr('src', '/images/' + img_url).parent().attribute('hidden', false);
});
```

Happy coding! :)

Comment: I cp'ed and it didn't work. I forgot to mention that the images are in a subfolder images so I edited the line [code]var img_url = $(this).attr('val');[/code] to [code]var img_url ="images/"+$(this).attr('val');[/code]

Comment: Huzzah! It worked. I mean... I got to work on the formatting with the images and what it does to the divs but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for the clarification of the location of the images.

Comment: Oh, I just changed a . To a , after 'src' that might have given you an issue.

Comment: As far as the hidden thing I would use a class called hidden, and .parent().removeClass('hidden').  The CSS for .hidden would be display:none

Comment: OH right I should definitely mention: val is not a recognized attribute of divs, which is (one) of the reasons the first example didn't work. I basically just got rid of the val and put it inside the tags and used var img_url = 'images/'+$(this).html();

Comment: Yup. value is, and it's used in forms, and .val() grabs it, but it won't grab a val attribute.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.image-url').on('click', function() {...});
```

You should read up on [jQuery selectors.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

**Edit**
Your example already has a valid selector in it. Is it not working? Perhaps it cannot find your jQuery library?

Comment: What is the difference between this and OP's selector? `div`?  `$('div.image-url').click(function () {`

Comment: Huh. Yeah. the `div` is the only difference. I tested them both on jsfiddle and they both worked. Not sure what he's asking then.

Comment: it appeared to be syntactly correct but I couldn't get it to work. I just re-looked and the files are where they should be and I tried re-writing: [code]$(document).ready(function () {
      $('div.image-url').click(function () {
        $("#image").attr("src","images/"+$(this).attr("val"));
                $("#image-holder").attr("hidden","false");
      });
    })();
[/code] Nothing. Somethings up